foreign key mismatch with foreign key pair which is a primary key pair
I'm trying to create the following sql tables' structure, but I can't figure out the problem. Here's an example:
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS c;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS b;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS a;
CREATE TABLE a (
    "Field1"    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
);
CREATE TABLE b (
    "Field1"    INTEGER,
    "Field2"    INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY("Field2") REFERENCES "a"("Field1"),
    PRIMARY KEY("Field1","Field2")
);
CREATE TABLE c (
    "Field1"    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    "Field2"    INTEGER,
    "Field3"    INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY("Field2") REFERENCES "b"("Field1"),
    FOREIGN KEY("Field3") REFERENCES "a"("Field1") -- or FOREIGN KEY("Field3") REFERENCES "b"("Field2")
);
insert into a values(1);
insert into b values(2,1);
insert into c values(3,2,1);

The last insert results in an error

foreign key mismatch - "c" referencing "b"

What's the problem?

Field1 is not the primary key of b and as such is not unique in b, the pair Field1, Field2 is.
The correct table definition is with FOREIGN KEY("Field2", "Field3") REFERENCES "b"("Field1", "Field2").
